# custom sidebar not responsive in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, sidebar

I am customizing an existing wordpress theme pytheas and part of that is adding a sidebar with  a different background colour, however when i set the width of the sidebar it does not become responsive, and if i do not set a width there will be no margin for the background colour

```
<table style="width:350px; max-width:100%; min-width: 10%; margin:0 auto">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<div style="background-color: #d0d5d8; font: arial;"><br />
<table >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> ...........
```

Comment: i dont know what else i could use to add the background colour

Comment: That is because fixed width elements are not responsive...either remove width=350px or use a percentage.

Comment: If the data isn't `tabular` data, don't use `tables`, use the syntactically correct `HTML` to mark it up, and then style it with `CSS` in the stylesheet.

Comment: can you give me an example of what syntactically correct html looks like? i was just using the table to set the background colour in a certain way

Comment: It depends on your content, what are you trying to display?

Comment: It is a sidebar with a different background colour than the content and the sidebar is like an extension of the header in the sense that they both line up, so that is why i am setting a width but i didnt realize it would not be responsive

Comment: You could just do `<div class="sidebar">sidebar content here</div>` `CSS` : `.sidebar { background:#ccc; }`. As a `<div>` is a `block-level` element, you don't need to specify a `width`

Comment: i would like to try that, although i am editing the sidebar in wordpress admin with the widget tiny mce, is there a way to embed the css into the file?

Comment: It's probably easier if you set up a local development environment, that way you're not working directly on a live site through the admin panel. That way you can modify the themes `CSS`, and view it locally before you upload the changes to the server.

Comment: oh don't worry i am doing everything locally. I just tried using div and not a table. it is responsive, but i still have the problem that the background does not extend right at the end of the header, i need the width to be a certain size and without specifying width i dont know how to do that